# Explain Query Bands in Teradata

Tags: teradata

Can anyone explain Query Bands in Teradata?
I've searched regarding this a lot, but wasnt able to get information which I can understand.
Please be a bit detailed.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you read the Teradata Manuals yet? What problem are you trying to solve that you are looking to Query Bands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**QUERY BANDING IN TERADATA:**

QUERY BANDING PROVIDES CIRCUMSTANTIAL WORKFLOW INFORMATION.

**Concept:**

Scientists will often band the legs of birds with devices to track their flight paths. Monitoring and analyzing the data retrieved via the bands provides critical information about the species.

The same process is followed by DBAs who need some more information about a query than what is available.

Metadata—such as the name of requesting user, work unit & the application name is important, Workload management will be tracking the entire use of data warehouse & query troubleshooting.
Query banding feature is used such a way that, these metadata details are linked to the query in database.

A query band can contain any number of name or value pairs such as initiating users corporate ID, department & location, also the time of the initiation execution started.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I would also like to ask, if you could give some specific example about application of QUERY BAND. From my current perspective the real purpose of QV is not very clear to me. The situation I have is following. We have datawarehouse, and we use QlikView to make various apps for various departments. We came to the QB topic because someone suggested, that it would be useful to track which user is accessing which data. Furthermore, I believe a security concept was also mentionde. Actually, can QB be used to control user access?

Comment: Finally, some specific example would be invaluably helpful. In particualr, if you can reference the situation I describe, the situation that we have in our company. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Prashanth provided a good analogy with birds and bands. Adam is asking for specific situations. I can come up with several examples, when query banding may be very useful:

1. Your system is used by hundreds of users via an Application Server with a custom application or a reporting application like Business Objects, Tableau or Qlikview. Application server connects to Teradata using one user ID, however the administrator would still like to know what users, departments and groups of users generate each query to be able to analyze later in DBQL or simply to allocate proper system resources using TASM. For this the application can be configured in such a way that each query is "banded" with information like "AppUser:User1;Appgroup:DataScientists;QueryType:strategic02". Despite the fact that Application Server uses one Teradata user and a limited number of connection to route all the queries from hundreds of users, each individual query is marked with information exactly which user has initiated the query. You can then perform all kinds of analysis based on this information.
2. Suppose you have a complex ETL application, and you want to track and analyze your execution of loads - what and when went wrong. Usually you would need to log all the steps of your ETL process, and in the logs you must specify unique Load ID, Process ID, Step ID, etc. You do this because you want to be able to understand what specific process caused this halt or a performance degradation, and without such logging it would not be possible to distinguish running of the same steps between different runs of your ETL application. A good alternative would be to switch on DBQL and embellish your queries with Query Band information with Load ID, Process ID, Step ID, etc. In this way you would have all necessary information in DBQL without the necessity to create additional elaborate log tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET QUERY BAND = 'name=value; name2=value;' FOR SESSION|TRANSACTION;
```

this will tag your query with some name value pairs. This can be used to manage your query's workload management for example in TDWM you have throttles and priority management hooks that will priorities all name2 types with the value "value". It means you can submit a very rich detail on the session or transaction

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you described can easily be done with QueryBanding; think of it as a "wagon of key-pair attributes in transit". you can access them via sql or prgrammatically with session attributes in bteq or jdbc for example.

Answer (score 0):

Necromancing... Existing answers do a good job at explaining how query bands work, but since I could not find a complete working example, I thought of adding one here.

Setting query bands in Teradata is already covered, so I will provide an example of how to set them from a .NET client:

```
private void SetQueryBands()
{
     TdQueryBand qb = Connection.QueryBand;
     qb["CustomApplicationName"] = "MyAppName";
     foreach (string key in CustomQueryBands.Keys)
     {
         qb[key] = CustomQueryBands[key];
     }

     Connection.ChangeQueryBand(qb);
} 

Connection = new TdConnection(GetConnectionString());
Connection.Open();
SetQueryBands();
```

More details can be found [here](https://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/tdnetdp/15.11/help/Teradata.Client.Provider~Teradata.Client.Provider.TdQueryBand.html).

To retrieve stored queryband data, [GetQueryBandValue](http://GetQueryBandValue) function can be used:

```
SELECT CollectTimestamp, QueryBand,
   GetQuerybandValue(queryband, 0, 'Key1') AS Value1, 
   GetQuerybandValue(queryband, 0, 'Key2') AS Value2, 
   GetQuerybandValue(queryband, 0, 'Key3') AS Value3, 
FROM dbql_data.dbqlogtbl
WHERE dateofday = DATE - 1
   AND queryband LIKE '%somekeyorvalue%'
```